# Prompting for credentials when using people picker control

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

I created a custom list, and added a people picker control. When trying to submit the form, I am getting prompted for a username/password. After 3 attempts or clicking canceled I get a dialog box saying the page cannot be displayed.

If I submit the form from the server, It will submit with not problems. So, this leads me to believe it's a permissions issue within the site collection, but I am stumped as to where to correct this problem. All of the users are within the Site Collections Owners group.

Comment: When you do it 'from the server', what account are you using, and is it a different account to when you're getting the login prompts? Does anyone else also get this problem?

Comment: I'm using the same credentials from both within the server, and from my desktop. Other users are having the same issue.

Comment: Ok, and what authentication providers are in use?

Comment: just claims based authentication

Comment: Do you have ADFS, or a cross-domain trust on your organisation?

Comment: we only have a standard 2008 R2 domain

Comment: Lastly, do your people picker selections 'resolve' (by clicking on the tick box on the bottom right of the picker), or do they show the prompt for credentials?

Comment: no problems with resolving people picker selection

Comment: the same problem in other pages(with or without people picker)?

Comment: Did you solved? I got the same problem.....

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation).

Answer (score 1):

Since the people picker resolves, I don't think there's any problem with your farm setup or how it talks to your domain (cross domain relationships, farm accounts, etc).

Since it seems to only fail when you save the item, I would inspect the ULS logs (c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\14\logs) for clues.

Next is to systematically try to narrow down the problem.

Try this with new lists with people pickers, see if it works in other lists (indicates problem with permissions in the original list, Inherit all permissions in the original list to fix).

Find out if it works with lists in other subsites (problem with permissions in original subsite. Inherit permissions in the parent site to fix).

Find out if it works with lists in other site collections (problem with permissions in original site collection. Rebuild permissions in the top level site in the Site Collection as per your policies).

Comment: I will start from the logs, and see where it leads.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem.  In our case, it was the Black Ice and IBM Server Protection services.  If these products are installed on your server, stop both of these services and see if that resolves the problem.  If so, then you can modify the Black Ice rules so it doesn't block the particular traffic with PeoplePicker that it perceives as an attack.